# WhatsApi 'no_routes' error

Tags: php, whatsapp

I wanted to use WhatsApi (https://github.com/mgp25/WhatsAPI-Official).

I followed the instructions about how to register my number and get a password but it did not work out -> it failed with no_routes error.

I also tried to use the built-in examples - registerTool.php and it also failed.

I got this response:

> ```
> stdClass Object
> (
>     [status] => fail
>     [reason] => no_routes
>     [retry_after] => 3600
> )
> There was a problem trying to request the code.
> ```

Do you know if this tool is still active? Am I using it wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problem was how to get the Whatsapp password.
I was not able to do that by registering using the documentation mentioned above (I'm still getting 'no_routes') but I was able to get the password and use the API by following the instructions explained in this post: https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/issues/983 . 
I still don't know what causes the no_routes problem but with the mentioned post - you can skip the registration part and go on to using the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest version of WART i am using WART-1.7.3.0.exe it does all the hardwork and send the Password via SMS or call the number you want to use.

Hope this helps